# Count within range, depending on value in column A

Tags: excel, google-sheets, countif, array-formulas

I'm trying to write a formula to sum up how many times something occurred within a calendar month.  My data looks like this (but much, much larger):

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WESRb.jpg)
[image: Example Data]

How for example might I count how many times `Brian` attended a meeting in the month of `May`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'Brian' could be anywhere in col B - col E (and col A is properly formatted as date), you can try a query to find the number of times Brian was present in May:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A:A, B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E}, "select count(Col1) where Col2 contains 'Brian' and month(Col1) = 4 label count(Col1)'' "))
```

If you want an overview per month of Brian's presence, you can try:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({text(A:A,"mmm"), B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E}, "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 contains 'Brian' group by Col1 label count(Col2)'' "))
```